# function returning error message: 'wordlist is not defined

Tags: python

When running this program I get this error message: NameError: name 'wordList' is not defined. Can't figure out why. Thanks.

```
import ahocorasick

def build_actree(wordlist):
    actree = ahocorasick.Automaton()
    for index, word in enumerate(wordlist):
        actree.add_word(word, (index, word))
    actree.make_automaton()
    return actree

if __name__ == '__main__':
    actree = build_actree(wordlist=wordlist)
    sent_cp = sent
    for i in actree.iter(sent):
        sent_cp = sent_cp.replace(i[1][1], "**")
        sent = '我草你妈'
        wordlist =['我草']
        print("屏蔽词：",i[1][1])
    print("屏蔽结果：",sent_cp)
```

`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please translate all your code to english, so we can understand what it says. If you print something in another language, we can't read it and you may as well just remove the print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I finally came up with:

```
import ahocorasick

def build_actree(wordlist):
    actree = ahocorasick.Automaton()
    for index, word in enumerate(wordlist):
        actree.add_word(word, (index, word))
    actree.make_automaton()
    return actree

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # correction : add wordlist initialisation 
    sent = '我草你妈'
    wordlist =['我草']
    actree = build_actree(wordlist=wordlist)
    sent_cp = sent
    for i in actree.iter(sent):
        sent_cp = sent_cp.replace(i[1][1], "**")
        print("屏蔽词：", i[1][1])
    print("屏蔽结果：", sent_cp)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you do in your code is :

```
actree = build_actree(wordlist=wordlist)
```

But there is no place where wordlist is defined. May be some code is missing.

Comment: thanks for your answer i am not defined before
actree = build_actree(wordlist=wordlist)
    sent_cp = sent

just
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sent = '我草你妈'
    wordlist =['我草']
    actree = build_actree(wordlist=wordlist)
    sent_cp = sent

it can work now